# Un/boxing в C# ; от object к int

Tags: c#, .net

Не могли бы вы подсказать, почему явный downcast числового object'a  (без предварительного upcast'a) доступен только к int, применяя к другим типам данных выдает ошибку invalidCastException. При предварительном upcast'e всё понятно , но ожидал , что без предварительного upcast'a работать downcast не будет.

Update. Как поправили - речь идёт об boxing/unboxing, а не о downcast'е.

Comment: все зависит от того, что хранится в этом `object`. Если там будет не `int` получишь ту же ошибку.

Comment: @Grundy хранится числовое значение, для примера 5.Это входит в диапазон всех числовых типов данных.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Преобразования к object и обратно называются [упаковка и распаковка](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing).

Особенностью распаковки value-типов является то, что нельзя распаковать один value-тип в другой.

В данном случае, так как в `object` уже хранится `int`, его нельзя распаковать в другую структуру.

Comment: Да, я не правильно выразился , это не downcast/upcast , а boxing/unboxing.Особенности value типов при упаковке и последующей распаковке понятны, здесь приведение только к первоначальному типу. Но похоже , записывая в object какое-то число , его можно распаковать только в int . Хотя мне казалось это вообще без предварительной упаковки не должно было работать

Comment: @Sparkll, нет, все зависит от того, какое именно число число ты записываешь. Если твой код просто `object o = 5` - то ты явно записываешь `int`, потому что любое число без указания - считается типом `int`, если же ты запишешь литерал `long`: `object o = 5L` - то и распаковать сможешь только в `long`

Comment: да, спасибо, буквально теперь сам и пришел к этому. теперь все разъяснилось

Comment: можете добавить в свой ответ ссылку на habr, интересную статью откопал https://habr.com/post/239219/

Comment: @Sparkll, я уже добавил на статью в msdn, в которой это все описано :) тем более статья довольно старая уже

Comment: Там просто пару примеров про Enum, который по default'у int, может кому-то будет полезно вспомнить, хотя скорее всего это мало кто увидит)

Comment: @Sparkll, если ответ помог, можешь отметить его галочкой